# How to call up windows 10 share dialog box from powershell or cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

In windows 10, if you right click on an image, you will find an option called "Share".

Clicking this opens up a dialog box where you can share the image via email, one note e.t.c.

Does anyone know how I can call this up from CMD or PowerShell? as I would like to add this feature to my app.

I have gotten to this point but get an invalid window handle error:

```
$Target = "C:\Users\igweo\OneDrive\Pictures\wallpapers\luca-zanon-26595-unsplash.jpg"

$KeyPath1  = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes"
$KeyPath2  = "*"
$KeyPath3  = "shell"
$KeyPath4  = "{:}"
$ValueName = "ExplorerCommandHandler"
$ValueData = (Get-ItemProperty("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\" +
  "Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.ModernShare")).ExplorerCommandHandler


$Key2 = (Get-Item $KeyPath1).OpenSubKey($KeyPath2, $true)
$Key3 = $Key2.CreateSubKey($KeyPath3, $true)
$Key4 = $Key3.CreateSubKey($KeyPath4, $true)
$Key4.SetValue($ValueName, $ValueData)

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $Target).DirectoryName)
$Item = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $Target).Name)
$Item.InvokeVerb("{:}")

$Key3.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath4)
if ($Key3.SubKeyCount -eq 0 -and $Key3.ValueCount -eq 0) {
    $Key2.DeleteSubKey($KeyPath3)
}
```

Also, using RUNDLL doesn't work either:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE NTSHRUI.DLL,ShowShareFolderUI C:\Users\igweo\OneDrive\Pictures\wallpapers\luca-zanon-26595-unsplash.jpg
```

Comment: Do you want to show the dialog or execute one of the items?

Comment: `$explorer = new-object -comobject shell.application` to control the shell, then `$Explorer.NameSpace("D:\folder\").ParseName("TestImage.jpg").Verbs()` will show it, and the verb name is `Share`, but trying to call `DoIt()` on it to invoke it, gives me `Exception calling "DoIt" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid window handle. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070578)"`. NB. that "how do I call this dialog up?" is not the same question as "how do I add sharing to my UWP app?"

Comment: Hi, I want to show the dialog for a selected image when I click on a button in my application. I am using powershell to run this. I got print to run by using for example: Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\igweo\500580_sole.jpg" -Verb Print | Out-Null;  However running:  Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\igweo\500580_sole.jpg" -Verb Share | Out-Null;   gives an error saying:  Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: No application is associated with the specified file for
this operation.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler You can only `DoIt` to verbs above the first separator in the context menu and the properties.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-implement-the-icontextmenu-interface So you will need to act like explorer and load the menu extension.

Comment: @Noodles honestly note sure how to use this, could you show me an example?

Comment: I don't think you can call this UI from an app external to Explorer in the context of Explorer (for security reason). However this "modern share" UI is available directly using the DataTransferManager UWP API. And this API is also usable in desktop application (with the UWP desktop bridge technology). There is a WPF demo application here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareSource not sure how to use this from Powershell (apart from building a custom .exe or .dll and calling it from Powershell of course)

Comment: Hi Simon, I am almost there. As you can see from my answer below. The problem now is how to close the winforms window after the user has selected his files or clicks outside the sharing dialog. I cannot find the event for when the user does not select any files or for when file selection is done so that I can close the main winforms window. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Simon Mourier for pointing me to the answer.
The solution can be found on https://github.com/daibatzu/electron-sharing

Using visual studio you can build an exe file, I have included instructions in the readme.txt

The generated exe is WindowsFormsApp2.exe
You can then share files by using:

WindowsFormsApp2.exe "C:\Projects\Javascript\photos\celeste.png" "C:\Projects\Javascript\photos\Silvercoins.jpg"

You can test this by opening a cmd prompt, navigating to the folder containing WindowsFormsApp2.exe and passing filenames as parameters.

Clicking outside the share dialog will close WindowsFormsApp2.exe
You will need to use visual studio to change the icon for this app unfortunately

I have included a release just in case you do not know visual studio or C#. You will need 7-zip (free download) to unzip it.

Once again, thanks to Simon.
This took way longer than I imagined.

EDIT

problems with github so zip file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jyBqO6jmGo5dSxw32LXa5lej1J3ElD34/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Note you can just reference the nuget package "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts", it will do all the UWP bridging work for you.